# Google Compute: Delete instance with deletionProtection flag toggled on

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I would like to delete an instance in Google Console, since it is no longer in use. However one of the other admins added the [deletionProtection](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preventing-accidental-vm-deletion) flag on the instance.

How can I delete the instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preventing-accidental-vm-deletion) you can find how to enable or disable deletion protection. You have to disable deletion protection before deleting your instance. When you disable deletion protection follow the [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/deleting-instance) to delete your instance. If you don't have access to change this instance - you should ask for additional permissions, more information you can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/).

Comment: Why is the selection disabled for this instance but not for other instances?

Comment: I've updated my comment, please check the last link.